# Sum of two cells where one must be negative?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need to add the product of one cell to another cell, but only if the second cell is a negative number. The product of the first cell is a result of another formula and is always positive. The product of the second cell may be either positive or negative but only added if a negative number is produced?

Comment: what do you want to return if it is not negative?

Comment: Do you want to use [if](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-if-function)?

Comment: A blank cell, if possible.

Comment: See edited answer below

Comment: You need **IF** function!

Answer (score 1):

Use a standard IF()

```
=IF(B1<0,A1+B1,"")
```

Where A1 contains the product of your first formula and B1 the product of the second.

Comment: Some versions of Excel uses ";" instead of "," as the separator (like my swedish version).